# Unity Operator `-=' cannot be applied to operands of type `float' and `UnityEngine.Vector3'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to make my character jump in Unity, but I get this error:
Operator `-=' cannot be applied to operands of type`float' and `UnityEngine.Vector3'

```
public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    public float speed = 6.0F;
    public float jumpSpeed = 8.0F;
    public float gravity = 20.0F;
    private Vector3 moveDirection = Vector3.zero;
    void Update() {
        CharacterController controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
        if (controller.isGrounded) {
            moveDirection = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
            moveDirection = transform.TransformDirection(moveDirection);
            moveDirection *= speed;
            if (Input.GetButton("Jump"))
                moveDirection.y = jumpSpeed;

        }
        moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        controller.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot modify a value for a single axis at a time, in C#. You have to reassign the entire vector:

```
moveDirection = new Vector3(moveDirection.x, moveDirection.y - (gravity * Time.deltaTime), moveDirection.z);
```

("copied" from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23824350/setting-specific-borders-in-x-and-y-axis-in-top-down-game/23832674#23832674)...it was the same issue!)

Comment: `moveDirection = new Vector3(moveDirection.x, moveDirection.y - (gravity * Time.deltaTime), moveDirection.z);` ".y" is missing in the answer - was probably a typo ;)